# li element with delete image on right with css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a list with delete image (button) on right side. When I put the `a` and `span` element into `li` element, and give the `float:right` style to the `span` element, it works in Chrome but not IE. IE renders delete image not same line. And on Chrome, delete image on second `li` not rendering top right of the `li`.

I need browser independent, just a item list with delete button on right side. Any other solution without `ul`,`li`,`span` elements appreciated. (Button or image must be separate element because I will add click handler to it.)

PS: Fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RMEeF/4/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul{
width: 200px;
}

li{
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#98bf21; 
}

li span{
background-image:url('http://www.kodlab.com/Image/delete.png');
    width: 16px;
    heigth: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}


</style>
</head>
<ul>
    <li><a>Foo</a><span></span></li>
    <li><a>neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</a><span></span></li>
</ul>​​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use an A-tag for actions, not a SPAN. Think semantic HTML.

Comment: try if you remove `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @mgraph i tried, but nothing changed..

Comment: @Diodeus: If we're going for the purity badge, you should use `POST` for destructive actions, not `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make `float:right` do what you want is to move the delete button before the link in the markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/RMEeF/5/

```
<ul>
    <li><span></span><a>Foo</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a>neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another option is to use `position:absolute` on the delete button, and `position:relative;` on the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/RMEeF/6/

```
li{  
   position:relative;
}

li span{
    background-image:url('delete.png');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    right:2px;
}
```

Adjust positioning as needed. This approach may interfere with the visibility of the other content if it overlaps, but the advantage is that it doesn't matter where in the markup you put the delete button.

And you should probably be using forms for the delete buttons instead of spans.

Comment: Both of them looks ok.. I won't use forms and button, i'll handle it with jQuery event handlers. Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense if you don't want anything to work if JS is disabled, but wouldn't be my choice.